# Error in azure devops multi stage pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

We have this error in our multi-stage pipeline. Anyone who has encountered this and what did you do to fix it? I really need some help. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This may indicate that there's an infinite loop or too many nested loops somewhere in the template.

Comment: do you know how can we eliminate the nested loops

Comment: I'm afraid it would be much clear if you could share your complete YAML here. Because we have no idea to guess what is your YAML look like just based on this error message pic:-)